# Avoid a trailing slash in bash when completing a directory name (like zsh)

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I'm on a Mac and the cp and mv commands are killing me due to them copying the contents of a directory if a trailing slash is present. It has bitten me more than once when I use tab completion to specify the directory I want to copy.

I have noticed zsh has a neat feature that removes the trailing slash if it's not needed after a space or enter key is pressed. Is there any way to have bash mimic this behavior?

Comment: I removed the osx tag as it's probably not related to the problem.

Comment: [Cross-posted](http://superuser.com/questions/362807/alter-bash-tab-completion-to-make-it-more-like-zsh) on [su]. [Please don't do that.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq#cross-posting)

Answer (score 5):

Put

```
set mark-directories off
```

in your `~/.inputrc`, and ensure you have `export INPUTRC=~/.inputrc` in `~/.bashrc`.

If you want to set this immediately then you can use bash's `bind` command:

```
bind 'set mark-directories off'
```

See also [How to avoid cp -r ~/some/folder/ . copying all files to the current folder's top level?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56114/how-to-avoid-cp-r-some-folder-copying-all-files-to-the-current-folders-to/56118#56118)