# How to avoid cp -r ~/some/folder/ . copying all files to the current folder's top level?

Tags: bash, cp

(**Update:** this happens on Mac OS X -- I am using Mountain Lion.)  It sometimes happen that I use the <kbd>tab</kbd> key to complete the path, so my command may be:

```
cp -r ~/some/folder/ .
```

but it turns out that the line above has a different behavior from

```
cp -r ~/some/folder .
```

the second line will copy the folder into the current directory, as `folder`, but the first line will copy all 7 files, 6 subfolders into the current directory, contaminating the current directory.  Since I don't do any source control using git or svn in that particular current directory, it actually has to be cleaned up manually, and it is quite a pain.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?  Such as by making a function, alias, or Bash setting?  I know I can remember this, but 2 months down the road, I can actually accidentally do the same thing again, so it is better to guard against this behavior.  (I would rather needing to use `cp -r ~/some/folder/* .` and `cp -r ~/some/folder/.* .` if that is what I really want.)

Comment: That behavior for the first example sounds strange and wrong and I am unable to reproduce it with GNU coreutils `cp`.  What version / OS do you have?

Comment: I was about to say my system does not behave this way. Neither on ubuntu on my laptop, centos server I control, or even cygwin at work..

Comment: Maybe he was really using rsync but changed it to cp for the question?

Comment: It actually works this way on BSD/Mac OS.  `-R ... If the source_file ends in a /, the contents of the directory are copied rather than the directory itself.` [man cp 1](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/cp/)

Comment: yeah never tried a bsd flavor, so was not aware. Interesting to note, thanks!

Comment: That is not normal behavior from `cp`. What OS did you observe it on? There is however a useful distinction between `cp -p foo bar` and `cp foo/ bar`: if `foo` is a symbolic link, copying `foo` copies the symbolic link whereas copying `foo/` copies its target.

Comment: yes, it is on Mac OS X Mountain Lion... I will add it in the original question

Answer (score 2):

To do this right would require re-parsing all of cp's options, and that's not a good idea.  But here's something that should come close:

```
# run cp command as-given, unless any argument ends in a slash
safecp() {
  for arg; do
    case $arg in */)
      echo "safecp: trailing slash in cp $*" >&2
      return 1
      ;;
    esac
  done
  cp "$@"
}
```

Alternatively, try putting

```
set mark-directories off
```

in your `~/.inputrc` to make bash not automatically add a slash when tab-completing directories.

Comment: or can we make `cp` behave this way: if the source has a trailing `/`, then stop with a warning, so we actually need to use `\cp` or somehow bypass the function if that's what we desire.  If there is no trailing `/` in the source, then just proceed with the usual `cp`.  I think not adding slash when tab-completing could be quite troublesome because we need to add the slash ourselves each time if there are several levels down for a path.

Answer (score 0):

You could certainly write a short bash function (with a recent version of bash, which can do regular expressions it's extremely simple), that would catch this kind of errors:

```
function cpr () {
    local src=...
    if [[ "$src" =~ /$ ]]; then
        # handle error
    else
        # proceed with copying
    fi 
}
```

the tricky part is determining what `dest` should be (you certainly want to skip the destination directory), if you want to cover all of `cp`'s options combinations (at least the GNU coreutils' `cp` has 3 different variations of syntax).

Using a specialised function that would correct it in-place might be better:

```
function cpr () {
    cp -R ${1%%/} ${2}
}
```