# Add trailing slash in bash completion of directory symbolic links

Tags: bash, symlink, autocomplete

I have a symbolic link for a directory,

e.g `ln -s /tmp /xxx`

Now when I type `/xx` and press <kbd>tab</kbd> key, bash would complete the line to `/xxx`

If I press it again it become `/xxx/`

Now, how can I ask bash to complete `/xx` to `/xxx/` automatically (provided that there's only one match)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Add the following line to your `~/.inputrc` file:

```
set mark-symlinked-directories on
```

See ["Readline Init File Syntax"](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Init-File-Syntax.html) in the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) for more on this topic.

Comment: WHY have I never searched for this issue? This has been bugging me for so long! (all my personal files reside under a symlink in my home folder)

Answer (score 3):

WORKSFORME on Ubuntu 15.10. What are you on? Are you sure you are using bash and not zsh?

Maybe just maybe :

```
echo 'set mark-symlinked-directories on' >> ~/.inputrc
echo 'export INPUTRC=~/.inputrc' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Mac, updated question

Comment: You have the exact opposite problem of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25734/avoid-a-trailing-slash-in-bash-when-completing-a-directory-name-like-zsh?rq=1 right?

Comment: I found this nice reference page about the settings that can go into inputrc, might be useful for someone who comes here: https://ss64.com/bash/syntax-inputrc.html