# Konsole auto-completion for link pointing to folder

Tags: bash, symlink, autocomplete

### Original Question

When `cd`ing into a folder through a link, auto-completes does not add the last `/` unless I hit <kbd>tab</kbd> twice. How to change that behavior?

---

### MWE:

```
cd /tmp/ && mkdir test && cd test && mkdir folder && ln -s folder link
```

Then do `cd lin` and <kbd>TAB</kbd>: it auto-completes to `link` and not to `link/` (but hitting <kbd>TAB</kbd> one more time auto-completes to `link/`).

---

### Clarification

- I want auto-completion to add the `/` before I want to move into another folder inside that folder.
- When `cd`ing into a folder that is not a link, the `/` is automatically added.
- There are no files with the same name as the link in that folder.
- Everything takes place in Konsole, which runs `/bin/bash`.

Comment: Why? To cd into a folder, the trailing slash is just noise. It's used to separate names of directories, and if no name follows, there is no reason to separate the first name from anything, i.e. `cd /tmp` already does the job.

Comment: Because, ultimately, I want to navigate to `link/test2/`.

Comment: Is Konsole performing autocompletion of your keystrokes, or a shell?

Comment: All of this takes place in Konsole.

Comment: It takes place in Konsole, but the tab-completion is performed by the shell. Which shell are you using, `zsh`? `bash`? Something else?

Comment: @Philippos Sorry, `/bin/bash`.

Comment: Side note (because of "Konsole auto-completion" in the title): Konsole is a terminal emulator, Bash is a shell. Auto-completion is a feature of the latter. Your Bash in xterm would auto-complete in the same way. See [*What is the exact difference between a 'terminal', a 'shell', a 'tty' and a 'console'?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4126/108618)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the answered [shared on that post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/275883/101324), and:

1. Created `~/.inputrc` and added to it:

```
set mark-directories on
set mark-symlinked-directories on
```

2. Added `export INPUTRC=~/.inputrc` to my `~/.bashrc`
3. Restarted konsole.

And now it works :-)